# What does arguments_ refer to?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement some plugins and found references to `arguments_` but, it is coming up as `undefined` in the console.  I cannot find any references online to this variable but, it seems to be something found in other JS code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not standard javascript. Some other part of the code or plugin framework must be providing it.

Comment: What's the context? Was this found within another plugin? If so, which?

Comment: Are you referring to `arguments`? See [MDN on arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every function has an array-esque [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) available in it's scope. It contains information such as what called the function, what arguments they passed, etc.

What you see with `arguments_` is most likely a third-party library that has stored some `arguments` variable from a specific function to be used later by their other functions. Without knowing what libraries you are including, though, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Backbone, Backbone.Marionette, Underscore, Jquery, and Bootstrap JS are all libraries being included.

Comment: @jslamka it could be any one of those, is there a reason you want/need to know, or are you just curious? I would just ignore it.

Comment: It was causing errors to pop up in the console which was breaking the rest of the code.  I have since changed the reference to arguments and it seems to be running okay now.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like js2coffee translates `arguments` to `arguments_` -- that's a bug. Should be `arguments`.

Comment: arguments is a keyword in coffeescript that should not be used. Use the ... operator instead. If you really need to use it, you can insert  pure javascript using backticks (`)