# Convert Google's new Universal Tracking Code to Coffeescript

Tags: google-analytics, coffeescript

I'm trying to integrate google's new analytics API with an application that uses Coffeescript modules. I'd like to convert their code to Coffeescript, but the automatic conversion from js2coffee.org fails. I'm trying to rewrite by hand but there is a comma I don't understand. Original JS code:

```
( function (i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
  i[r]=i[r] || function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)
  }, // --------------------------------------- What is this comma?
  i[r].l=1*new Date();
  a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
  a.async=1;
  a.src=g;
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
```

Translated Coffeescript

```
((i, s, o, g, r, a, m) ->
  i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r
  i[r] = i[r] or ->
    (i[r].q = i[r].q or []).push arguments_

  i[r].l = 1 * new Date()

  a = s.createElement(o)
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]

  a.async = 1
  a.src = g
  m.parentNode.insertBefore a, m
) window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga"
```

Throws error `arguments_ is not defined`. Which makes sense, since that's not the variable name. Not sure how to translate this by hand though--all those commas in the JS are throwing me off.

Comment: This says it's a bug with js2coffee. Maybe that's all that's going on. Still think the comma use is odd though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847324/what-does-arguments-refer-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> **Summary**
>
> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.
>   [...]
>   **Description**
>
> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a `for` loop.

That is an odd use of the comma operator but you have to keep in mind that the JavaScript you're looking at has probably been mangled by a preprocessor or two so it isn't intended for human consumption. The comma operator is usually only used in for-loops and sometimes in `return`s when someone is trying to be clever.

You can safely replace that comma with a semicolon in your mind while translating the JavaScript to CoffeeScript. Or just leave the JavaScript as JavaScript since:

1. It isn't meant for you to edit or maintain.
2. It will all be JavaScript in the end anyway.

Comment: Because CoffeeScript is part of my build process, and I want to dynamically swap in different values for UA key and domain based on build environment, it makes sense in my case I think to convert to CoffeeScript.